# Наибольшая возрастающая подпоследовательность за O(n log(n)), не идёт алгоритм

Tags: c++

Нужно ещё вывести ответ. Никак не могу понять, что в моём алгоритме не так.
Вот описание, по которому делал алгоритм:
*d[i](i = 0...n) — число, на которое оканчивается возрастающая последовательность длины  i, а если таких чисел несколько — то наименьшее из них. Изначально мы предполагаем, что d[0] = -INF, а все остальные элементы d[i] = INF. Заметим два важных свойства этой динамики: d[i - 1] <= d[i], для всех i = 1...n и каждый элемент a[i] обновляет максимум один элемент d[j]. Это означает, что при обработке очередного a[i], мы можем за O(log n) c помощью двоичного поиска в массиве d найти первое число, которое больше либо равно текущего a[i] и обновить его.*

*Для восстановления ответа будем поддерживать заполнение двух массивов: pos и prev. В pos[i] будем хранить индекс элемента, на который заканчивается оптимальная подпоследовательность длины i, а в prev[i] — позицию предыдущего элемента для a[i].*

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

ifstream in ("input.txt");
ofstream out ("output.txt");

#define INF numeric_limits<int>::max()

int main () {
  int n;
  in >> n;
  vector<int> d(n, INF); 
  d[0] = -INF;
  vector<int> a;
  vector<int> p(n, 0), prevv(n, 0);
  p[0] = -1;
  int tmp;
  while (in >> tmp) {
    a.push_back(tmp);
  }
  int maximum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j = distance(d.begin(), upper_bound(d.begin(), d.end(), a[i], [](int x, int z) {return (x <= z);}));
    if (d[j-1] < a[i] && d[j] > a[i]) {
      d[j] = a[i];
      p[j] = i;
      maximum = max(maximum, j);
      prevv[i] = p[j - 1];
    }
  }
  vector<int> tmpv;
  int parent;
  parent = p[maximum];
  while(parent != -1) {
    tmpv.push_back(a[parent]);
    parent = prevv[parent];
  }
  out << maximum << endl;
  copy(tmpv.rbegin(), tmpv.rend(), ostream_iterator<int>(out, " "));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Минуту назад человек написал, что у меня неправильно реализована функция upper_bound. Могу сказать, что даже без предиката идёт точно такое же кол-во тестов. 
Можно эту строчку изменть на `int j = distance(d.begin(), upper_bound(d.begin(), d.end(), a[i]));` и ничего не поменяется

Comment: "не идет алгоритм"? Что кокретно в нем не так? Скорость выполнения или что?

Comment: @AndrioSkur не все тесты на сайте с проверкой идут